# (bounded linear) orthogonal projections on Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $T:H\to H$ bounded and linear, such that $T$ is an othogonal projection (i.e. $T^*=T^2=T$), is then T always zero on $im(T)^\perp$ and the identity on it's image, $im(T)$?

I read often something like that, and my first thoughts about the claim:
If $T:im(T)\oplus im(T)^\perp \to im(T) \oplus \{0\} $ and $h=h_1+h_2\in H$ arbitrary with $h_1\in im(T)$ and $h_2\in  im(T)^\perp $, then for $x\in im(T)^\perp$: $\langle T(x),h_1+h_2\rangle=\langle T(x),h_1\rangle +\langle T(x),h_2\rangle =\langle T(x),h_1\rangle=\langle x,T(h_1)\rangle=0$. It follows $T(x)\in H^\perp=\{0\}$ for $x\in im(T)^\perp$, which means that $T$ is zero on $im(T)^\perp$.

I'm not sure, if the argumentation is correct. But why should $T$ be the identity on $im(T)$?

Comment: Is $T^*$ the adjoint ?

Comment: yes, $T^*$ is the adjoint of $T$.

Comment: Because $\forall y\in\text{im}\,(T)\colon (T-I)y=(T-I)Tx=(T^2-T)x=0$.

Comment: A.G. thanks! Why you don't write this in an answer?